# How to pass arguments to Gradle from IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle, command-line-arguments

In  IntelliJ Idea 13.0.1 I created Gradle Project and add java plugin and create new task hello, as you can see from the picture but how can I execute:

```
hello -q
```

for example or

```
clean build --refresh-dependencies -Pparam=10
```

Is there a way to pass easy Gradle command line options

[image]

And one more why Gradle's tasks like

```
tasks
```

are not shown in **Gradle tasks window**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately it's current not possible in stable version, but there is already solved [ticket](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-117792) that will be introduced in IDEA 13.0.2 (EAP is already available)